# Subsetting list by values in a column in r

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset

I want to subset a list of dataframes so that it returns the list in the same structure, but excluding rows from each dataframe that meet a condition in one column.

Say I have the following list:

```
col1<- round(rnorm(5, mean = 5), digits = 0)
col2<- round(rnorm(5, mean = 5), digits = 0)
col3<- round(rnorm(5, mean = 5), digits = 0)
a <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3)

col1<- round(rnorm(5, mean = 5), digits = 0)
col2<- round(rnorm(5, mean = 5), digits = 0)
col3<- round(rnorm(5, mean = 5), digits = 0)
b <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3)

col1<- round(rnorm(5, mean = 5), digits = 0)
col2<- round(rnorm(5, mean = 5), digits = 0)
col3<- round(rnorm(5, mean = 5), digits = 0)
c <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3)

my_list <- list(a,b,c)
names(my_list)<-c("df1", "df2", "df3")
```

This provides a list:

```
> my_list
$df1
  col1 col2 col3
1    3    6    5
2    5    4    4
3    6    5    6
4    5    3    6
5    4    4    4

$df2
  col1 col2 col3
1    6    5    5
2    6    5    5
3    5    6    6
4    5    4    5
5    6    5    5

$df3
  col1 col2 col3
1    6    7    5
2    6    5    5
3    5    6    4
4    4    6    5
5    5    6    4
```

Say I want to remove all rows that have values in col3 that are less than 5 producing:

```
> my_list
$df1
  col1 col2 col3
1    3    6    5
3    6    5    6
4    5    3    6


$df2
  col1 col2 col3
1    6    5    5
2    6    5    5
3    5    6    6
4    5    4    5
5    6    5    5

$df3
  col1 col2 col3
1    6    7    5
2    6    5    5
4    4    6    5
```

I have tried using lapply to no avail:

```
result <- lapply(my_list, function(x) {
  return(x[x$'col3' < 5])
}
)

> result 
$df1
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

$df2
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$df3
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: missing a comma? `return(x[x$'col3' < 5, ])` (also no need for the quotes around "col3" when using `$`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the quotes and the comma. Changing this didn't seem to fix the problem, but following Yuriy's suggestion below worked perfectly.

Comment: not sure why it's not supposed to work - works perfectly for me. Your example is not very reproducible, for the lack of set.seed() - that may be the reason?. Obviously, you need to change to `x[x$col3 >= 5, ]` - have you done that?

Comment: my apologies. you are right, this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**base**

```r
set.seed(1)
l <- lapply(my_list, function(x) subset(x, col3 >= 5))
l
#> $df1
#>   col1 col2 col3
#> 1    5    5    5
#> 2    5    5    5
#> 3    4    4    5
#> 
#> $df2
#>   col1 col2 col3
#> 1    6    5    7
#> 2    3    6    5
#> 4    5    5    5
#> 
#> $df3
#>   col1 col2 col3
#> 4    4    5    7
#> 5    7    4    7

do.call(rbind, l)
#>       col1 col2 col3
#> df1.1    5    5    5
#> df1.2    5    5    5
#> df1.3    4    4    5
#> df2.1    6    5    7
#> df2.2    3    6    5
#> df2.4    5    5    5
#> df3.4    4    5    7
#> df3.5    7    4    7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: May I ask how you would then collapse this list into a single dataframe like the tidyverse solution above, but using base r?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

result <- function(x) {
  x %>% 
    filter(col3 < 6)
}

map(my_list, result)
```

This returns a `list` of `data.frame`s where `col3` is less than 6.

```
$df1
  col1 col2 col3
1    5    4    4
2    4    4    4

$df2
  col1 col2 col3
1    6    7    5

$df3
  col1 col2 col3
1    6    5    5
2    5    5    5
3    5    5    3
```

You can combine into a single `data.frame` by using `map_df`:

```
map_df(my_list, result)
```

This gives us:

```
> map_df(my_list, result)
  col1 col2 col3
1    5    4    4
2    4    4    4
3    6    7    5
4    6    5    5
5    5    5    5
6    5    5    3
```